# Autocopy selected text on drop-down list to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, clipboard

I want to ask if there is a way to copy text automatically to clipboard when user selects option on drop-down list.

Comment: Check this out buddy http://stackoverflow.com/a/11347714/2261259

Comment: i think this post is a good answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this for copy value

```
   window.clipboardData.setData('Text',str);
```

[Demo](http://bowser.effectgames.com/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/)